# pebbleCentral:watchDidConnect never gets called on iOS

Tags: ios, pebble-sdk

I have an old Pebble Classic watch, upgraded to latest firmware (3.8.2) and using latest Pebble-SDK.

I have followed the few simple steps to install SDK, setup an Xcode project and adding the code to initialise and connect:
https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/mobile-apps/ios/

My problem is, that the delegate method pebbleCentral:watchDidConnect never gets called!

I am using the Pebble Time app on the iPad to install the watchApp in the watch, so I know the iPad is connected to the watch. The same iPad runs the iOS app, which apparently does not discover the watch.

I have tried to import an old test project from a colleague, who had it running a year or two ago. Same watch, same watchApp, but of course older firmware and SDK versions. Same result...

I think the documentation on the pebble site is quite simple and easy to follow. However, I feel I am missing some explanations of how and when this watchDidConnect is supposed to be triggered.

I am most likely missing some simple step somewhere, but I am quite lost in where to look!

Any ideas are welcome!

EDIT: My code looks like this:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import PebbleKit;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<PBPebbleCentralDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) PBWatch* connectedWatch;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral].delegate = self;

    [[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] run];

    NSLog(@"Pebble initialised");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)pebbleCentral:(PBPebbleCentral*)central watchDidConnect (PBWatch*)watch isNew:(BOOL)isNew {
    NSLog(@"Pebble connected: %@", [watch name]);
    self.connectedWatch = watch;
}

- (void)pebbleCentral:(PBPebbleCentral*)central watchDidDisconnect:(PBWatch*)watch {
    NSLog(@"Pebble disconnected: %@", [watch name]);

    if ([watch isEqual:self.connectedWatch]) {
        self.connectedWatch = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `-run` method, after setting up your Pebble central? I noticed that the code snippet in the link you posted does not show the central's `delegate` being set.

`[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral].delegate = self; // Set your delegate`

`[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral].appUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"Your Pebble App UUID"]; // Set the app UUID`

`[[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] run]; // Call -run on the central`

Comment: I have edited my post with a code sample. So, yes, I am calling 'run'. I have tried setting the UUID as well, with no luck.